# Set member data of classes object

Tags: c++, object

I am having some trouble with understanding why I cannot set a string of a member object inside of another object. This is the particular line that just gives blank output:
cout << c1.getC2().getS2() << endl;
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class class2 {
  string s2;
  public:
         string getS2() const {return s2;};
         void setS2(string s) {s2.assign(s);};    
};

class class1 {
  string s1;
  class2 c2;
    public:
      string getName() const {return s1;};
      void setName(string s) {s1 = s;};
      class2 getC2() const {return c2;};
      void setC2(class2 c) {c2 = c;};
};

int main() {
  class1 c1;
  class2 c2t;
  string input;
  getline(cin, input);
  cout << "input: " << input << endl;
  c1.getC2().setS2(input);
  cout << c1.getC2().getS2() << endl;//This line is always blank
  //c2t = c1.getC2();
  //c2t.setS2(input);
  //c1.setC2(c2t);
  //cout << c1.getC2().getS2() << endl;

 cin.get();   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c1.getC2()` returns a *copy*.

So, when you do `c1.getC2().setC2(input)`, you're invoking `setC2` on a *copy* and that change is immediately lost.

Look into *references* for your member functions.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.